# Why aren't the rationals a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

We define a compact subset of some normed vector space $V$ to be any subset $S$ where every sequence $\{\mathbf{x}_{n}\}$ in $S$ has a subsequence which converges to some $\mathbf{x}$ in $S$.

Then it seems like it must be a duplicate but I can't find a good reason anywhere, why aren't the rationals a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$? How can I most easily show this? I'm trying to better understand the notion of compact subsets.

Comment: Not every sequence of rationals converges to a rational. For instance, consider rational approximations to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Consider the sequence $a_n = n$.

Comment: @JohnMa Right, right. Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be instructive to describe an open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: As @goblin suggests, consider the set of open sets $\left\{N_1(q) : q \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ which is an open cover of $\mathbb{Q}$. Any finite subcover will have an element whose centre $q_\text{max}$ is largest, so clearly $q_\text{max}+1$ is not in the subcover.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason: a compact subset of the reals is closed and bounded (Heine-Borel theorem), and the rationals are distinctly *not* bounded.

Answer (score 2):

A compact space is complete.

Another reason: a compact subspace is closed. And precisely, the closure of $\mathbf Q$ is $\mathbf R$.

Answer (score 0):

A space must be complete in order to be compact. Complete means that every Cauchy sequence converges, that is every sequence "approaches" to a point that belongs to the considered set.
For example, the sequence
$$
a_n=\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n} \bigg)^n
$$
is a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ but it does not converge into $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete and thus is not compact.